# Smallest planar graph with two non-homoemorphic plane embeddings?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Apologies for asking a question which probably has a well-known answer:

What is the smallest (not necessarily simple) planar graph with two non-homeomorphic embeddings into the plane?

I am interested in both the case where vertices are labelled, and also the case where they are unlabelled.  (In my application, vertices are labelled, but labels need not be unique.)

As a follow-up, what is the smallest planar graph with inequivalent embeddings onto the sphere?

(In case it makes a difference, I assume that graphs are undirected.)

Comment: Does labelling the vertices mean that two different embeddings of $K_4$ in the plane are non-homeomorphic?

Comment: Hi Ben - thanks for this comment.  Staring at the example for a few minutes I guess the answer is "yes" -- which is good to know, but I'm going to generalise the question include to the labelled and unlabelled vertices.  (In my application, distinct vertices might have the same label.)

Comment: A triangle with an extra edge pointing in, resp. out? I don't think one can do better...

Comment: For the sphere, take the triangle with two extra edges, pointing into the same, resp. different hemispheres

Comment: If we don't have to be simple, then a double edge will serve in place of a triangle.

Comment: if you allow non-simple graphs, the triangle can be degenerate (i.e. two parallel edges, or even a loop --- if loops are allowed)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments:  if someone writes up an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Hello Ross! You might also have a look at Tutte's [census paper](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v15/cjm1963v15.0249-0271.pdf), in particular Figures 3 and 4. Figure 3 shows the nine different _rooted_ planar embeddings of the four two-edge graphs. If you consider unrooted embeddings into the plane, then the two-vertex graph with one bridge and one loop still has two different embeddings.

Comment: What about 1 vertex with two self-loops?

Comment: If "smallest" is first in terms of the rank of the fundamental group (so the smallest graphs are trees) and then by the numbers of vertices, then the smallest with 2 non-equivalent planar embeddings is a tree of 7 vertices made of one "root" with 2 branches of size 2 and 2 branches of size 1.

Comment: @YCor: you are right that the 1 vertex map with two self-loops also has two different embeddings into the plane (one where the outer face has degree 2, one where it has degree 1). Both this example and the one bridge + one loop example correspond to a single embedding into the sphere (where there is no distinguished outer face), but if you add an extra edge (either a bridge or a loop) then you can get different embeddings on the sphere as well (to answer Ross's last question).

Comment: @RossDuncan: by the way, Jackson and Visentin's "An Atlas of the Smaller Maps in Orientable and Nonorientable Surfaces" is also a handy reference!

Comment: @NoamZeilberger yes I was aware of this (I read the discussion!).